# rails 4 permit polymorphic association file upload

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    mount_uploader :file, PictureUploader
end

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end
```

View:

```
h1 Add a new Ticket

= form_for @ticket do |f|
    = render partial: "fields", locals: {f: f}

    = f.fields_for :picture do |p|
        div
           = p.label :file
           = p.file_field :file, :multiple => true

    div
        = f.submit "Create a Ticket"
```

Controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)

    t = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    t.debug "================================"
    t.debug ticket_params
    t.debug "================================"

    @ticket.init_sp(ticket_show_path(Ticket.generate_id), request)

    @ticket.errors.add(:base, "Are You Spammer?") if @ticket.spam?

    if @ticket.errors.empty? and @ticket.save
      redirect_to ticket_show_path(@ticket.token), notice: "Ticket created successfully. Message sent."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

 private
  def load_ticket
    @ticket = Ticket.find_by_token(params[:token])    
  end

  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:customer_name, :customer_email, :subject, :body, :department_id, picture_attributes: [:file])
  end
end
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/tickets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-14 16:22:28 +0300
Processing by TicketsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3ToWruQi0Pgyo1wvRz9yOib5k13yV
Vs05dXAaWA4NuM=", "ticket"=>{"customer_name"=>"Alex Drobazko", "customer_email"=
>"drobazko@gmail.com", "subject"=>"Sample Subject", "department_id"=>"", "body"=
>"Sample Body", "picture"=>{"file"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x34f6
5f0 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/drobazko/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140614-
8144-hj7xsk>, @original_filename="28122007(001).jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg"
, @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ticket[picture][file][]\"; fi
lename=\"28122007(001).jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch
::Http::UploadedFile:0x34f65d8 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/drobazko/AppData/Local/
Temp/RackMultipart20140614-8144-q2595k>, @original_filename="f3.jpg", @content_t
ype="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ticket[pictur
e][file][]\"; filename=\"f3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}}, "commit"
=>"Create a Ticket"}
Unpermitted parameters: picture
D, [2014-06-14T16:22:28.099362 #8144] DEBUG -- : ===============================
=
Unpermitted parameters: picture
D, [2014-06-14T16:22:28.103362 #8144] DEBUG -- : {"customer_name"=>"Alex Drobazk
o", "customer_email"=>"drobazko@gmail.com", "subject"=>"Sample Subject", "body"=
>"Sample Body", "department_id"=>""}
D, [2014-06-14T16:22:28.107362 #8144] DEBUG -- : ===============================
=
```

Problem is Nothing writes in Picture table but it does in Ticket table (see log).
Any suggestions?

EDIT: when I tried to change in View **= f.fields_for :pictures do |p|** to **= f.fields_for :pictures do |p|** but it gave me an error **uninitialized constant Ticket::Picture**

Also, I tried to change:
**params.require(:ticket).permit(:customer_name, :customer_email, :subject, :body, :department_id, picture_attributes: [:file])**
to
**params.require(:ticket).permit(:customer_name, :customer_email, :subject, :body, :department_id, pictures_attributes: [:file])** (singular to plural) but without effect.

Interesting issue:
Once I restarted a server and put this in view:

= f.fields_for :pictures do |p|

The File button is disappeared on form ))

Answer (score 2):

You have **`has_many pictures`**.So your **`ticket_params`** should be like this

```
def ticket_params

params.require(:ticket).permit(:customer_name, :customer_email, :subject, :body, :department_id, pictures_attributes: [:file])

end
```

Notice the plural **`pictures`** in **`pictures_attributes`**.

**Update**

And also this line

```
= f.fields_for :picture do |p|
```

should be like this

```
 = f.fields_for :pictures do |p|
```

Comment: I tries both **pictures** and **pictures_attributes** but without effect. It doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my question. Your last suggestion gives me an error **uninitialized constant Ticket::Picture**

Comment: @LeshaPipiev Did you tried my both suggestions at once?

Comment: I tried but changing f.fields_for :picture do |p| to f.fields_for :pictures do |p| gave me an error uninitialized constant Ticket::Picture

Comment: @LeshaPipiev You should also change `picture_attributes` to `pictures_attributes`

Comment: I have changed it. But I can't try because of ** uninitialized constant Ticket::Picture** error in my View

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55626/discussion-between-pavan-and-lesha-pipiev).